# How to mock Injected value relying on a qualifier using JerseyTest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mockito, hk2, jersey-test-framework

I'm trying to mock a controller/resource including the jax-rs layer. The class has dependencies that need to be injected. 
It however also has some `String` values that are injected using a qualifier interface.

Basically, I'm using JerseyTest to run a single controller and use HK2 for dependency injection. I created a `ResourceConfig` and registered a `AbstractBinder` to bind the injected classes.

This works fine for regular injected dependencies, but when the the additional `@SomeQualifierInterface` annotation is added, it crashes with the following error:

```
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=String,parent=ThingsController,qualifiers={@com.company.SomeQualifierInterface()},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,10035302)
  ...
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.company.ThingsController errors were found
  ...
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.company.ThingsController
  ...
```

See the simplified full code example below:

#### Controller / Resource

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/things")
public class ThingsController {

  @Inject
  private Logger log;

  @Inject
  @SomeQualifierInterface
  private String injectedQualifierValue;

  @GET
  public Response getThings() {
    log.info("getting things");
    System.out.println("Injected value: " + injectedQualifierValue);
    return Response.status(200).entity("hello world!").build();
  }
}
```

#### Qualifier interface

```java
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import javax.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface SomeQualifierInterface { }
```

#### Producing service

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeProducerService {

  @Produces
  @Dependent
  @SomeQualifierInterface
  public String getQualifierValue() {
    return "some value!";
  }
}
```

#### Test

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;


public class MockedThingsControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

  private Logger logMock = mock(Logger.class);

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ThingsController.class);
    resourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bind(logMock).to(Logger.class);

        bind("some mocked value").to(String.class); // Doesn't work
        bind(new SomeProducerService()).to(SomeProducerService.class); // Doesn't work
      }
    });
    return resourceConfig;
  }

  @Test
  public void doSomething() {
    Response response = target("/things").request().get();
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    verify(logMock).info("getting things");
  }
}
```

#### POM

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.27.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
  <version>2.28</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the Jersey test framework, but in hk2 you can create a mock service (maybe think about using @Stub) in your test area and give it an @Rank(1) on the implementation.  That'll cause it to be used in favor of the other one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

First, use the `AbstractBinder` from `org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder` instead of `org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.AbstractBinder`.

Second, create a class that extends `AnnotationLiteral` and implements the interface.

Last, bind the value to a `TypeLiteral` and set the qualifiedBy to the AnnotationLiteral.

Full code:

```java
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.AnnotationLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.TypeLiteral;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;


public class MockedThingsControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

  private Logger logMock = mock(Logger.class);

  @Override
  protected Application configure() {
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ThingsController.class);
    resourceConfig.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bind(logMock).to(Logger.class);
        bind("some mocked value").to(new TypeLiteral<String>() {}).qualifiedBy(new SomeQualifierLiteral());
      }
    });
    return resourceConfig;
  }

  @Test
  public void doSomething() {
    Response response = target("/things").request().get();
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    verify(logMock).info("getting things");
  }

  static class SomeQualifierLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<SomeQualifierInterface> implements SomeQualifierInterface {}
}
```